# knockout.js and not binding a dropdownlist on page load

Tags: knockout.js

I have an observable array binding to a dropdownlist.  The dropdownlist is populated on page load via ASP.NET MVC Html Helpers, but since the observable array is set to [], it removes everything.  Is there a way to not have it remove everything on page load or initial apply bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to set the options from the observable array at a later time (from an AJAX call maybe?). Knockout doesn't have any built-in way to do this. I see you have at least three options:

1. The obvious way is to have your ASP.NET code fill out the observable array instead of the select list. Then Knockout will do the right thing and populate your drop-down list.
2. Use a custom binding that wraps the `options` binding, but ignores empty arrays:

   ```
   ko.bindingHandlers.optionsNotBlank = {
       update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
           var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
           if (value.length)
               ko.bindingHandlers.options.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingAccessor);
       }
   };
   ```
3. Set the `options` binding on the drop-down list dynamically. This is not a published feature, but does use an exported Knockout method. Instead of using the standard `data-bind` attribute, you'll be using the `ko.applyBindingsToNode` method and passing it a binding object after you've filled in your observable array. You'll need to be careful to only call `ko.applyBindingsToNode` once though.

   ```
   viewModel.myArrayOfItem(newValues);
   if (!boundDropDown) {
       ko.applyBindingsToNode(document.getElementById("mydropdown"), { options: viewModel.myArrayOfItems }, viewModel);
       boundDropDown = true;
   }
   ```

Edit:

Here's a fourth option based on the comments using a "dirty" flag:

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.optionsNotBlank = {
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
                isDirty = element._isDirty;
            if (isDirty || value.length) {
                element._isDirty = true;
                ko.bindingHandlers.options.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingAccessor);
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Darn, well I got around it by doing some conditional checks that at least made sense.  Be nice if you could do something like this where you can check the elements value.  All your options wont work for me but I will accept it as an answer since they are viable solutions.

Comment: Why won't they work for you? Are you looking to delay all bindings, not just options?

Comment: 1. I dont want huge JSON strings in my HTML. 2. I dont want to ignore empty arrays since I will be clearing the observable at some points. 3.  I dont want to reference the select list directly like that, fills dirty.

Comment: I could do a custom binding that sets a dirtly flag the first time, and every time after that binds the array to the select list, basically combining both 1 and 2 above.

Comment: Good idea. I added it to the answer.